# How to change the .PyCharm30 cache/settings folder?

Tags: caching, indexing, directory, pycharm

On Linux PyCharm saves index and caches in the ~/.PyCharm30 folder/directory which can grow to >1.7GB. How can I change it to another location?

Comment: You can't unfortunately. You can change your main project directory, but not the application data.

Comment: Or simply move the cache file (content.dat.storageData) somwhere else and replace it with a symlink ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the cache folder is in ~/.Pycharm30/system/

You can change the locations of the system directory and other directories by changing the PyCharm_home\bin\idea.properties file.

You will need to adjust the following parameters:

```
idea.config.path
idea.system.path
idea.plugins.path
```

You can read the documentation, here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/project-and-ide-settings.html.  I hope this helps.